# Is it possible to deallocate memory for the N last elements of a thrust::device_vector without using resize?

Tags: cuda, thrust, gpu

I'm using a `device_vector` in order to store information about an array of user input data. This information is necessary in order to speed things up when I call the second kernel, which runs the main algorithm.

After the end of the first kernel the `device_vector` will contain only a small amount of important elements. So for example if initially the `device_vector` has a size of 10000 in the end only 10-20 elements will be describing the user input data.

What I'm doing right now is, I use the function `thrust::remove` in order to remove the unnecessary values, however if I understand correctly, this function doesn't really remove the unnecessary values, but returns an iterator to the last necessary value.

For example suppose that we have this array:

```
0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 8 0 0 0 0 13 0 0
```

if I call `remove` for value 0, it will do something like this:

```
5 8 13 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and it will return an `end` iterator to the last necessary element, which in my case is 13.

However, I would like to use this information for the second kernel, and if I understand correctly, the unnecessary elements will still be allocated, so I would be using memory that I don't need.

My question is, can I, by having the `end` iterator to the last necessary element, remove the unnecessary elements without using `resize`?

`resize` isn't very efficient because it removes all the elements, and allocates memory for the necessary elements as well, but the memory is already allocated so I don't see the point of doing this.

Comment: I don't believe that `resize` necessarily reallocates upon a shrink. That's the whole point of the `shrink_to_fit` function.

Comment: Hello, so should I use the `resize` function and then the `shrink_to_fit` function or are these two working together which means that just calling `resize` would be enough? If you want you can make an answer so that I can accept, I wasn't aware of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`device_vector::resize` doesn't necessarily cause a reallocation to occur upon a shrink event. It is allowed to do so, but as of Thrust 1.8, the current implementation does not.

For your example, you should be able to simply call `resize(3)` without worrying about a reallocation occurring.